# .Net Core API cant return result including System.Net.IPaddress

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core-webapi

My Database is Postgressql which has INET type in .net i should use IPadress for mapping,but when i use it i get Page cant be reached error on client side,when i use String i get an error from database which says cant be cased to string from Inet

```
      var rslt = _context.tenmins.Where(s => s.m_turbine_id == IPAddress.Parse("192.168.39.82" )&& s.m_time_stamp >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)).Take(2).ToList();
        return rslt ;
```

how to change to string after i get result,here is the screen shot of my result which could not be returned on browser!
[image: BackEndResult]

Comment: What error did you get? I made a test with `public IPAddress IP { get; set; }` and `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL`, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, it is caused by that `IPAddress` is not friendly to serialize. You could try to implement your own `JsonConverter`.

1. `IPAddressConverter`

   ```
   public class IPAddressConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return (objectType == typeof(IPAddress));
       }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           return IPAddress.Parse((string)reader.Value);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register Converter

   ```
   services.AddMvc()
           .AddJsonOptions(opt => {
               opt.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IPAddressConverter());
           }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
   ```
3. Controller Action

   ```
   public List<Address> PostSql()
   {
       var rslt = _context.Addresses.Where(s => s.IP == IPAddress.Parse("192.168.39.82")).Take(2).ToList();
       return rslt;
   }
   ```